# Perl search for files and rename them while copying to different directory

Tags: perl

I'm trying following code to search for .txt files and rename them while copying it to different directory.

```
#!/bin/perl
use File::Basename;
@txtfiles = <*/*.txt>;
foreach my $file(@textfiles){
    $dir = dirname($file);
    $file = basename($file);
    $file =~ s/(\d+)/$dir/; //renaming number with $dir
`mkdir -p summary` unless -d summary;
`cp $file summary`;
}
```

Above code gives error saying no such file to copy however print statement at each line shows correctly (renamed file names)

Comment: *Always* `use strict; use warnings;`!

Comment: In Perl to comment any line use `#` not `//`.

Comment: Thanks for suggestions, i will correct it. Could you please help me where the code is going wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***NOOOOO!***

Don't use system commands -- especially since there are Perl commands that you can use.

```
`mkdir -p summary` unless -d summary;
`cp $file summary`;
```

Use the **Perl** commands!

```
use File::Copy;       # Standard Perl Module. USE IT!
...
mkdir 'summary' unless -d 'summary';   # No need for `-p`
copy $file, 'summary';
```

Here's a revised script:

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw(say);

# use File::Basename;  -- No need for this in this version
use File::Copy;

# What files do you want to find?
# Do you want to find the immediate files or the
# files in the subdirectories?

my @text_files = glob('*.txt');  # Immediate files only

mkdir 'summary' if not -d 'summary';   # Make this dir before the loop
for my $file ( @text_files ) {
    next unless -f $file;              # Make sure this is a file you want to copy!
    #
    # No need for 'dirname' and 'basename' with '*.txt' glob
    #
    if ( not copy $file, 'summary' ) { # Check the outcome of this command.
        warn qq(Could not copy file "$file" to "summary".);
    }
}
```

Let us know if you need to copy files in subdirectories rather than just in the immediate directory. Maybe you can use `make_tree` found in `File::Path`, or the Perl version of `find` from `File::Find`. These are standard Perl modules that all Perl installations have.

---

### Addendum

> I don't want current directory. The files are resides inside one directory i.e. `foo/text_v0001.txt`, `foo/text_v0002.txt`, `foo_au/text_v0003.txt`, `foo_au/text_v0004.txt` continues.... I want to replace the numbers with directory name e.g. `foo/text_v0001.txt` should renamed to `text_foo.txt` and `foo/text_v0002.txt` should renamed to `text_foo.txt` (since in same folder we can't have same name files, we can add part2 and the end of second file i.e. text_fooPart2.txt).

That last part is a doozy, and it's a new requirement too. I need to verify that a file doesn't already exist with the same name, and if it does, I need to make sure that I find the next available name.

If I find that a file already exist, I'll loop incrementing a duplicate file counter until I find a file name that doesn't already exist.

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw(say);

use File::Basename;
use File::Copy;
use File::Glob;                        # Improved Glob matching.

use constant {
    DIRECTORY           => 'summary',
};

# What files do you want to find?
# Do you want to find the immediate files or the
# files in the subdirectories?

#
# Let's do a more sophisticated pattern making sure we're catching
# the files we want.
#
my @text_files = glob('*/*.txt');      # Subdirectories only
mkdir DIRECTORY if not -d DIRECTORY;   # Make this dir before the loop

for my $file ( @text_files ) {
    my $dir_name  = dirname $file;
    my $file_name = basename $file;
    say "DEBUG: On '$file'.";
    #
    # Let's make sure that the file name matches the expected
    # pattern. If the substitution doesn't succeed, we assume
    # this file shouldn't be copied, and skip it.
    #
    # I'm serching for a file that has the suffix '_vxxxx.txt' where
    # 'xxxx' is some number. I remove the number and the letter `v`,
    # and add in the directory name.
    #
    if ( not $file_name =~ s/_v(\d+)\.txt$/_$dir_name.txt/ ) {
        warn qq("$dir_name/$file_name" has not been copied.");
        next;
    }
    #
    # If the name matches, make sure it's a file
    #
    if ( not -f $file ) {
        warn qq("$file" is not a file and wasn't copied.");
        next
    }
    #
    # Now make sure file name is unique
    #
    if ( -f DIRECTORY . "/$file_name" ) {         # File name already exists
        say qq(DEBUG: Duplicate File '$file_name' detected!);
        my $dup_file_counter = 2;
        ( my $file_no_suffix = $file_name ) =~ s/\.txt$//;
        #
        # Find a non-matching name
        #
        for (;;) {
            my $new_file_name = $file_no_suffix . "_part_$dup_file_counter.txt";
            say "DEBUG: New file name '$new_file_name'";
            say qq(DEBUG: if ( not -e @{[DIRECTORY]} . "/$new_file_name" ) { );
            if ( not -e DIRECTORY . "/$new_file_name" ) {
                $file_name = $new_file_name;
                last;
            }
            else {
                $dup_file_counter += 1;
            }
        }
    }


    if ( not copy $file, DIRECTORY . "/$file_name" ) { # Check the outcome of this command.
        warn qq(Could not copy file "$file" to directory ") . DIRECTORY . qq(".);
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the replay and suggestions  David,  i need files in the sub-directories. My Requirement is look for files in sub-directories and modify the file name with directory name it found and than copy to different directory i.e. summary

Comment: Do you need the files under the CURRENT directory too? Using `*/*.txt` as a pattern gets the files under the subdirectories, but not the current directory? What about a file like `foo/bar/barfoo.txt`? Do you want this copied too? I'll update my answer as soon as you reply.

Comment: i don't want current directory. the files are resides inside one directory `i.e. foo/text_v0001.txt  foo/text_v0002.txt foo_au/text_v0003.txt foo_au/text_v0004.txt` continues....  i want to replace the numbers with directory name e.g. `foo/text_v0001.txt` should renamed to `text_foo.txt` and `foo/text_v0002.txt` should renamed to `text_foo.txt` (since in same folder we can't have same name files, we can add part2 and the end of second file i.e. text_fooPart2.txt). Kindly let me know if i'm not clear to you.

Comment: Thank you so much David. You are genius, it works well. Could you please guide me how do i learn to code like this? could you please guide me some documents/tutorials and tips for perl?

Comment: The basic text is called the [Llama Book](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920018452.do). It's a great book for quickly picking up the syntax and understanding the basics of Perl, but it doesn't go into modules (especially the standard modules such as `File::Copy`) or OOP Perl. However, it'll get you into the language very quickly.

Comment: thanks again, i will start with this book

Answer (score 0):

in the loop you are using `@textfiles` instead of `@txtfiles`. Use `strict`

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl
use File::Basename;
use strict;
use warnings;


my @txtfiles = glob("*.txt");
foreach my $file(@txtfiles){
     my $dir = dirname($file);
     $file = basename($file);
     $file =~ s/(\d+)/$dir/; # renaming number with $dir
     `mkdir -p summary` unless -d "summary";
     `cp $file summary`;
}
```

Comment: This will work for current directory only.

Comment: Yes, you are correct serenesat...this will work only for current directory. @Morad that was typo while typing here... :)

Comment: @praneeth You can use the find shell command in order to search for txt files wherever you need

Comment: i have noticed a point here before using cp operation the $file state will be modified (means the file name changes however physical it was not changed on system) and at the point of cp stage it tries to look for modified $file names which are not exist and throws error saying No such file or directory. so now i want two variables something like `cp filename1 (before modification) filename2 (after renaming files)`